# Problems taking picture in android, close my application "(...) ResultInfo {who = null, request = 1, result = 0, data = null} to activity ..."

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-photos

Good friends, A few days I've been trying to solve this problem, I see that there are several in the forum, but none have managed to solve my problem.

I have an ImageView and a Button to take the picture.
In the event of the button I have this code:

```
 oButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //oImageActual is the final ImageView
                        oImageActual = oView;
                        Intent intent =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                           
                        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                    }                       
                });
```

and the result of the activity, I have this one:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {            
        if (data != null) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {                    
                 Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                 oImageActual.setImageBitmap(photo);                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that several times it works, and fails several times, I mean, funcina, take the photo and puts it in ImageView, but many times you close the application. I have to reboot the phone to work again.

This is the main problem we get:

(...)java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity(...)

If anyone has an answer, please be waiting here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "take the photo and puts it in ImageView, but many times you close the
>   application."

If i am understanding this right, you are closing the activity before the result is returned. onActivity result only gets the result if the parent activity is not closed during the whole event.

Comment: How to prevent the application from closing?

Comment: you can override onBackPressed, and ask the user if he really wants to exit. you should allow him to exit anytime though

Comment: but the error comes out is because you can not summarize the activity and therefore forced to finish it. My question is how to keep close the application Forze

Comment: you can't force it. The user can close your application one way or the other.